# Double For Each Loop (How to work around this issue?) Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Background info: The aim of my tool is I have a form where when you enter a name in a cell and it brings up all of the details attached to that persons name using vlookups and basic excel code.

Now what I am doing is I would like to click a button and make vba run all the names through this tool so the details from the form are all stored in a table. The code below returns the first column of data from the first box in a For Each Loop (which this is doing fine if the second for loop is removed). The problem I have is I need a second for each loop to return a second column worth of data but the problem with this is the first for each loop only runs once and then it will run the second for each loop multiple times to return the second column of data that I need. What I need is either 1 for each loop which can take 2 ranges or a completely different way to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim h As Range

Set copySheet = Worksheets("WIN RATES")

With copySheet
    For Each r In .Range("H3", .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Len(r) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("NEW! FORM CHARTS").Range("E4").Value = r.Value
            Worksheets("NEW! FORM CHARTS").Range("E4").Resize(, 1).Copy
            Worksheets("Full Over 2.5 & BTTS list").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        With copySheet
            For Each h In .Range("N3", .Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Len(h) > 0 Then
            Worksheets("NEW! FORM CHARTS").Range("M4").Value = h.Value
            Worksheets("NEW! FORM CHARTS").Range("M4").Resize(, 1).Copy
            Worksheets("Full Over 2.5 & BTTS list").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    End If
                Next h
            End With
        End If
    Next r
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The way I want it returned is like this:

```
Name 1 | Name 2 
tom    | 17846
mike   | 16253
steve  | 10987
Anne   | 16243
```

But, understandingly, my data is doing this:

```
Name 1 | Name 2 
tom    | 17846
       | 16253
       | 10987
       | 16243
```

The idea is that excel will run through all the names in the list and fill in the form with Name 1 and Name 2, together with these names input onto the form, they will fill in the rest of the form with the vlookups in the excel sheet itself, so my end goal is to have this kind of table where vlookup1 and vlookup2 is from the excel sheet:

```
Name 1 | Name 2 | VLOOKUPDATA1 | VLOOKUPDATA2
tom    | 17846  |       1      |     80%
mike   | 16253  |       8      |     90%
steve  | 10987  |       6      |     23%
Anne   | 16243  |       3      |     43%
```

I know this is long winded, just ask me if you need any clarification.

Comment: Just to mention, make sure you fully qualify the range when using `Rows.Count`.  Without putting the sheet, i.e. `Worksheets("Full Over 2.5 & BTTS list").Rows.Count`, it'll pull the number of rows from whatever the active sheet is, and that may not be what you want.  So also in your `With copySheet` loop, make sure to add the "anchor" `.` before `Rows.Count` to make sure it's counting the `Rows` on `copySheet`.

Comment: I don't think you need to 2 `with` blocks

Comment: This is a lot tougher without seeing the data that you are grabbing.

Comment: @Kyle The excel based tool I am working on is online, my website is thatstat.co.uk and can be downloaded there. Might help if you are a soccer/football fan too haha

Comment: I downloaded workbook and I still don't know what data you are trying to massage. Provide a specific sample in your post or at least identify the worksheet. I don't see individuals, only teams.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two loops, just the one acquiring data from columns "H" and "N" in each iteration. With that much data it'll take an awfully long time copying and pasting one cell at a time - you'd be far better reading to and writing from an array.

Code below shows both points. I really can't see why you're writing each item to the "NEW! FORM CHARTS" worksheet only to write over it with the next loop, so I've left that part out of your code. You'll see that there's a small bit of extra coding that just deals with the case that the two columns don't end on the same row.

I'd also recommend you read about classes as this will vastly simplify and probably speed up your tasks.

```
Dim home As Variant
Dim away As Variant
Dim r As Long, rMax As Long, rOffset As Long
Dim output() As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WIN RATES")
    home = .Range(.Range("H3").End(xlDown), .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2
    away = .Range(.Range("N3").End(xlDown), .Range("N" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value2
End With

rMax = WorksheetFunction.Max(UBound(home, 1), UBound(away, 1))

ReDim output(1 To rMax, 1 To 2)
For r = 1 To rMax
    If r <= UBound(home, 1) Then output(r, 1) = home(r, 1)
    If r <= UBound(away, 1) Then output(r, 2) = away(r, 1)
Next

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Full Over 2.5 & BTTS list")
    rOffset = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row, .Range("A2").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range("A1").Offset(rOffset).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
End With
```